# AMD Radeon RX 6800 XT not visible within Debian/WSL2

Tags: graphics-card, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a 6800 XT GPU running on Windows 10 21H2 (OS Build 19044.1889) with a WSL2 Debian installation (kernel version `5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2`). The graphics drivers (Adrenaline 22.5.2) are installed on the Windows system and working fine:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\Quant> wmic path win32_VideoController get name
Name
AMD Radeon RX 6800 XT
```

However, when I open a WSL2 terminal and run `lspci` or `glxinfo` I would expect to see information about the GPU, but I don't:

```
DESKTOP-NHBC022@arman: ~ $ lspci
831e:00:00.0 3D controller: Microsoft Corporation Device 008e
DESKTOP-NHBC022@arman: ~ $ glxinfo
Error: unable to open display
```

Things I've tried:

- Update the kernel to 5.10.x
- check that `/dev/dxg` exists (it does)
- `sudo apt-get install libegl-mesa0` (I have version `18.3.6-2+deb10u1`)

I tried reading this tutorial; https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gpu-compute, but it seems to assume that your GPU is already available within WSL, which mine isn't.

How can I get Debian to see / utilise the GPU? Note that I'm not interested in GUI apps, which I understand is a Windows 11 feature. I just want the GPU to be available within Debian for use with Tensorflow.

**UPDATE**:

I have uninstalled debian and installed Ubuntu from scratch. Same issues:

```
quant@DESKTOP-NHBC022:~$ uname -r
5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
quant@DESKTOP-NHBC022:~$ lspci
5254:00:00.0 3D controller: Microsoft Corporation Device 008e
```

Comment: Your not trying to use CUDA with AMD hardware are you? Because the link you shared only applies to Nvidia hardware

Comment: @Ramhound I don't think what you said about the link is correct, as it applies to AMD, Nvidia and Intel GPUs.

Comment: FWIW, [this link](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-rad-win-wsl-support) tells me that WSL is supported for RX 6800 series cards, although it's not clear to me from that article whether I need to do anything in addition to just installing the windows drivers.

Comment: Make sure your GPU is actually supported [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/directml/gpu-tensorflow-wsl), had the wrong link in my clipboard, was hoping for the simple explanation, looks like it’s definitely supported

Comment: @Ramhound is it expected that if a GPU is supported it will appear within the WSL instance automatically, or do I need to install some kind of "wsl" driver?

Comment: 21H2, supported GPU with the appropriate driver installed, and 5.10.43.3 WSL2 distribution should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately all of my remaining Windows 10 systems have older GPUs that don't support WSL GPU Compute, so I can't confirm this, but ...

I strongly suspect that you have everything you need already.

> check that `/dev/dxg` exists (it does)

That's actually a good indicator that GPU Compute is ready.

> when I ... run `lspci` or `glxinfo` I would expect to see information about the GPU, but I don't

- From the manpage:  *The `glxinfo` program shows information about the OpenGL and GLX implementations running on a given X display*

  Since you aren't able to run X under Windows 10, it's no surprise that `glxinfo` fails.  Even on Windows 11, if I unset my `DISPLAY` variable, `glxinfo` gives me the same message.

  So that seems normal to me.
- `lspci` returns the same thing on Windows 11 for me.  That's expected as well.  The actual device is a virtual one created by WSL that maps the essential capabilities from the virtual device to your physical GPU.

  I can confirm that, even with `3D controller: Microsoft Corporation Device 008e`, the basic TensorFlow/DirectML test [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/directml/gpu-tensorflow-wsl#install-the-tensorflow-with-directml-package) works properly.

So I would recommend giving TensorFlow/DirectML a try at this point.  If you run into problems with *that*, I'd recommend opening a question on Stack Overflow (as it would be off-topic here on SU).

I'll do what I can to help on Stack Overflow if you do run into issues, but no promises that I can be useful on the topic.  I'm pretty much a TensorFlow newbie, but I do have a decent amount of experience with WSL.

Side note -- Here's the recipe I used for running TensorFlow on WSL:

- I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 where the default Python is 3.10-based.  Even on Debian Bullseye, the package version is 3.9 from what I see, so that's actually *too new* for `tensorflow-directml`, which only runs on versions up to 3.7.
- For that reason, and since I have Docker Desktop installed, I decided to run in a Python 3.7 Docker image, which is Debian-based.
- The GPU needs to be shared into the Docker container via either `--gpus all` or a `--device` construct.
- And the kicker is that the GPU compute functionality in WSL is "injected into" the WSL instance at startup.  The directory `/usr/lib/wsl/lib` is created as an "overlay" mount.  But it *doesn't* exist in the Docker container, of course.  So we need to share it in as well, and set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` appropriately.  Courtesy [this blog](https://nnt339es.hatenablog.com/entry/2022/07/31/045059) from just a few days ago apparently.  I haven't translated it, but at least the commandline is in English ;-).
- Finally, the `protobuf` package installed with `tensorflow-directml` is too new and needs to be downgraded per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72493690/11810933).
- I'm using an nVidia GPU, but the process should be the same for AMD.
- I'm on the 5.10.102.1 kernel as well, but using WSL Preview release 0.64.0 on Windows 11.

With all that in mind ...

```
docker pull python:3.7
docker run --gpus all --mount type=bind,src=/usr/lib/wsl,dst=/usr/lib/wsl -e LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/wsl/lib -it --rm python:3.7 bash
pip install protobuf==3.20.*
pip install tensorflow-directml
python
```

The [quick test here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/directml/gpu-tensorflow-wsl#install-the-tensorflow-with-directml-package) then worked in that Python session.

Comment: You were right. I tried the `tensorflow-directml` example in the link you provided and it (allegedly) executed on my GPU. Thanks for that.

Comment: Now to try and get all of this running with tensorflow 2...